# Why is the Stack Overflow business page trying to show me this Facebook image?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-business

Recently I found a bug on [Stack Overflow business](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/?ref=topbar_help).

See the first lines of webpage. And also the link of that page is available (look the image top carefully).

---

[image: Bug]

Full Page

[image: Full Page]

---

Comment: Do you have any extensions enabled? What browser are you using? I can't reproduce it here with Google Chrome.

Comment: Google chrome and Edge both

Comment: Odd. Are you behind a (work / school) firewall?

Comment: No bug in Edge , only in google chrome

Comment: What is the bug? where do I need to look in your screenshot?

Comment: See the top of webpage , few lines of html are a bug

Comment: Can't reproduce this, can't see that img in dev tools either

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That glitch is caused by the fact you have JavaScript disabled which will lead to a render of content in the  `<noscript>` tag.

There happens to be an attempt to get a facebook pixel in the page when you have javascript disabled. Unfortunately the content is  this:

```
<noscript>&lt;img  height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1621132604871265&amp;amp;ev=PageView&amp;amp;noscript=1"&gt;</noscript>
```

Had that content not been html encoded you would have had an image from facebook tracking. Now you'll just get the content as is.

That page is riddled with tracking links btw. If you care about other services not knowing where you have been you better not load that page, or load it in a private session.

Comment: Yeah , now I get it , you are right,  javascript is disabled in my browser