# The Hubspot account for Stack Overflow Business has expired

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-business

I was looking on another Stack Exchange site (*[Does a Wizard's spellbook need to be a book?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131177/does-a-wizards-spellbook-need-to-be-a-book)*) and after reading the question was just looking around. I scrolled down and clicked a link in the bottom, because I was wondering what it was...

The linked said: Stack Overflow Business:

[image: Freehand indicator]

The link points to: https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/

After I clicked I saw a 404 page:
[image: Stackoverflowbusiness 404 page]

I guess this is not the correct page content?

Comment: This is likely more on-topic on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com), since it involves another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: But it is about Stackoverflow Business... not stackexchange business... But I see your point.... Can the question just be moved? Or do I need to ask the question again over there?

Comment: You can modflag it for migration, but that might take a while. Generally, delete + repost is faster. You could just leave it too...

Comment: The question can stay here. The footer on SO also points to that domain, via the 'Talent' and 'Engagement' links.

Comment: I don't see what you see. https://i.stack.imgur.com/u60zY.png

Comment: Huh? For me it's redirecting to https://stackoverflowbusiness-450622.hs-sites.com/, which serves a legit-looking page.

Comment: @rene Ha, I love the blatant unrendered tracking pixel code at the top there.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ I recalled I saw that [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366566/578411) ;)

Answer (score 8):

It seems there was an error on the side of HubSpot: https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1037634281856753664

[image: Nick_Craver tweet]